# Regex for .htaccess to change urls

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have urls from a joomla install that are coming in like:

http://blah.com/blog/543-this-is-the-blog-title

I need to change them for wordpress to:

http://blah.com/this-is-the-blog-title

I know it can be easily done using regex in the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be done easily.

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^blog/[0-9]+-(.+)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Make sure this is the first rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file.

Comment: That did the trick. I understand up until (.+) What does that bit do?

Comment: Part after numbers and hyphen is captured into `(.+)` which is then used as target URI in `/$1`. THen comes some flags. See reference: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html